# How to remove entries in linux mint boot loader

Tags: grub, linux-mint

How do I remove unwanted entries in linux mint boot loader?

Comment: Which version of Mint are you using and which version of the grub boot loader?

Comment: linux mint 9. And the default boot loader for it. I installed it through wubi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to [modify](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId514088) the `/etc/default/grub` configuration. The cheap way is to modify `grub.cfg` but it will be overwritten at some arbitrary future package upgrade or install and the entries you don't want will magically reappear.

Answer (score 1):

I had two installations of Linux Mint 12 in other hard disk, and I removed the unwanted hard disk installation.

The process was to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change (via`pico /etc/default/grub`) `timeout=10` to `timeout=5`

I believe that work was by:

```
update-grub
```

but the next `sudo aptitude remove linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic` is not my actual kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If your unwanted entries are for older versions of the Linux kernel, after new ones have been installed by the package update, you can manually remove the packages for those old versions.

For example, after an upgrade to 2.6.28-18, my machine still had a pair of references to 2.6.28-11 in the boot loader.  I removed them by executing:

```
sudo aptitude remove linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic
```

Other entries will have to be removed by hand from the grub configuration files.